# Why does my for loop not check every character?

Tags: python, for-loop, password-checker

So I'm a bit of a beginner at python and I cant for the life of me figure out why it wont check and add on for every letter

```
def howstrong (password):
    points = len(password)
    charactersallowed = ["!", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "=", "+"]

    for ch in password:
        if ch.isupper():
            points= points+5
        elif ch.islower():
            points = points+5
        elif ch.isdigit():
            points = points+5
        elif ch in charactersallowed:
            points= points+5
        else:
            points = points+0
        return points
```

If I input a password of Password! into my code it tells me my points are 14 but for this password it should be 24? Below I will add the rest of my code but I doubt that its in that part and I believe that there's an error in my for loop somewhere.

```
def checkingmain():

    while 1:
        p = input("\nEnter password: ")
        if len(p) < 8 or len(p) > 24:
            print("Password must be 6 to 12 characters.")
        elif input("Re-enter password: ") != p:
            print("Passwords did not match. Please try again.")

        else:
            score= howstrong(p)
            if not score:
                print("Invalid character detected. Please try again.")

            else:
                if score <= 0:
                    print("your password is weak",score)
                elif score>0 and score<20:
                    print("your password is medium",score)
                else:
                    print("your password is strong",score)
            break
```

I'd appreciate if someone would get back to me with an understandable solution for a somewhat python beginner.

Answer (score 5):

It only ever checks the first character, because you return inside the loop. Move your return statement back one indent, so it is not inside the for loop.

Comment: Would you have any idea on how to stop the code adding +5 for every capital? This is a new problem that i have now encountered. If you dont know it should be fine. I dont want to trouble you any more :) thank you for the fast response too :))

Comment: You need a flag variable. Set `has_capital = False` before the loop, check that it is still False before you add 5 and set it to True.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have your return statement inside the loop, it only runs the loop one time before returning from the function. If you move your return statement back one tab it should work

Answer (score 0):

The return statement is inside the for loop , so when your program reaches the end of the for loop for the first time, it simply returns from the function, so your for loop is terminated. A little change in your code like shown below will help you.

```
for ch in password:
    if ch.isupper():
        points= points+5
    elif ch.islower():
        points = points+5
    elif ch.isdigit():
        points = points+5
    elif ch in charactersallowed:
        points= points+5
    else:
        points = points+0
return points
```

Hope it helps !